# I want to store apostrophe in message box such as john's watch.It show erreor near 's

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Please help me to store apostrophe. I m creating a website (C#, .net, SQL Server) and want to have a message box for the users but the problem is that when I inserts any message such as `John's` it shows an error near `''s'`.

Please tell me how could I store apostrophe in database

I used `nvarchar`, `varchar` and everything but failed to store apostrophe containing messages.

A general solution is to write message with double apostrophe but this is not a solution for a website

Comment: Give use your code and the error's information.

Comment: All you have to do is google "sql server apostrophe."

Comment: All you have to do is to use `Commands` with `Parameters`

Comment: Do you know Boby? http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 4):

You are open for [SQL-Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Don't concatenate strings to build your query. Instead use `SQL-Parameters`.  That also makes your code more readable and prevents errors like yours.

Here's an example:

```
int amt;  
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    var sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Message(UserID, Message) VALUES(@UserID, @Message);";
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userID); // passed as argument
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", txtMessage.Text); // f.e. "John's"
        con.Open();
        int inserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The same works also with other sql like `UPDATE` commands.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to escape Apostrophe by another Apostrophe.

For example have a look at:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2f75/1

```
CREATE TABLE tblTEst( col1 NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO tblTest
  (Col1)
SELECT 'John''s'
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use a prepared statement (or whatever the equivalent in C# is) where your SQL only contains placeholders and you pass the actual values through a different method.

In a character literal, the single quote `'` can be used by simply doubling it:

```
insert into foo (bar)
values
('John''s');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `CHAR(39)`between **john** & **s**  like this: `'john'+CHAR(39)+'s'`

Comment: why use double apostrophe or char(39) to store words having apostrophe..??..Lets take example of this post which i have posted here..I've used here apostrophe and similarly any user may use words with apostrophe then what will be the solution for this kind of problems..??